# Microsoft generated Azure AD Connect account

Tags: active-directory, azure

During the installation of Azure AD Connect MSFT generates a local account used for validation and other purposes.  This is no problem.

During the course of subsequent syncs this account validates against the on-prem (disabled)Guest Account since this generated account has a "NULL SID".  It then locks the disabled "Guest Account"   Again in most environments this is not a problem.

However in this environment they track any logins and they have noticed this lockout.  While it does not cause any operational issues they want to know:
1) can they change the generated account to another on-prem account?
2) is this normal operating procedure

I have advised against changing this configuration. However a link to MSFT documentation of the topic would be outstanding.  For the life of me I can't find any.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The Azure AD Connect [documentation for custom installation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect-get-started-custom/) describes how to use an existing service account instead of the

> Use an existing service account
>
> By default Azure AD Connect creates a local service account for the synchronization services to use. The password is generated automatically and unknown to the person installing Azure AD Connect. If you use a remote SQL server or use a proxy that requires authentication, you need a service account in the domain and know the password. In those cases, enter the service account to use. Make sure the user running the installation is an SA in SQL so a login for the service account can be created. See Azure AD Connect accounts and permissions

I found this by searching for "[azure ad connect account](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=azure+ad+connect+account)", which led to [Azure AD Connect: Accounts and permissions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect-accounts-permissions/), which has a link to [Custom installation of Azure AD Connect](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect-get-started-custom/).

Comment: Thanks Philippe.  That is the documentation provided to client when installing AADC.  However this does not review the use of the Null SID account by O365.